# How to hide specific lines of css from IE 7 and IE 8

Tags: css, internet-explorer

So I have been trying to make some css drop down menus work in IE 7 & 8

They work great on other browsers.

site is: http://hanling.focusww.com

I've got a block of css and I contains some lines that I want to hide from the IE 7 & 8

I've marked the lines with '*' at the end.

```
#menu a:visited {
  color:#f9f6e0;
  display:block;
  font-weight:700;
  padding-bottom:10px; //kill this in ie *
  padding-left:12px;
  padding-right:12px;
  padding-top:10px;  //kill this in ie *
}
```

Can someone point me to an article that explains how to do this?

Comment: If your design does not need to be pixel-perfect, you might consider using non-fixed units for margin/padding, like "em" or percentage. Maintaining separate style sheets for IE can be more trouble than it's worth. Most users will not be visiting your site in multiple browsers, and probably don't care if it looks slightly different in different browsers.

Comment: All of these answers have been awesome, but so far, none have worked. I've got a WordPress child theme that is not cooperating. sigh.

Comment: maybe post specific sections of HTML and CSS that are not working, or create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do that the simple way with `IE conditional comments`:

**HTML**

```
<!--[if IE 7]> <html class="ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]> <html class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
```

**CSS**

```
#menu a:visited {
  color:#f9f6e0;
  display:block;
  font-weight:700;
  padding-bottom:10px; //kill this in ie *
  padding-left:12px;
  padding-right:12px;
  padding-top:10px;  //kill this in ie *
}

.ie7 #menu a:visited,
.ie8 #menu a:visited, {
  padding-bottom: 0; //kill this in ie *
  padding-top: 0;  //kill this in ie *
}
```

..or also possible with `CSS-Hacks`, more: http://www.webdevout.net/css-hacks#in_css

```
#menu a:visited {
 color:#f9f6e0;
 display:block;
 font-weight:700;
 padding-bottom:10px; 
 padding-bottom:0\9; //kill this in ie *
 padding-left:12px;
 padding-right:12px;
 padding-top:10px;  
 padding-top:0\9; //kill this in ie *
}
```

Comment: Hacks seem shorter, but the first method looks more compliant. Thanks - Most complete answer.

Comment: Just a warning for some people like me...conditional comments are not longer supported on IE 10+

Comment: @Simone Yeah, that's the reason why some people add a `<http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"...` tag in their `head`. As this question is about 7 & 8 I will leave my answer untouched ;) However, if feature detection (https://modernizr.com) is not possible, you should take a look at http://browserhacks.com/

Comment: I tried that tag in the head using  `<!--[if IE]>` but it doesn't work

Comment: @Simone What value have you assigned to the `content`-property?

Comment: I tried the solution of Mr. Alien, so basically I linked a new stylesheet

Comment: @Simone The `content`-property I talked about, is to apply to the `meta`-tag above. This could help you https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801214(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: that was clear, I used the edge option but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You can use IE conditional comments, can't hide specific styles from IE, or even @yckart link is cool to be referred, but better use a specific stylesheet

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
    Only Shows Up In IE7
    <link href="#" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if IE 8]>
    Only Shows Up In IE8
    <link href="#" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Good to know - basically ie7.css and ie8.css?

Comment: @Nohl anything :) but the things you specify inside comments only applies to that specific version or you can use `<!--[if IE]>` for targeting IE in general

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

```
#menu a:visited {
 color:#f9f6e0;
 display:block;
 font-weight:700;
 padding-bottom:10px; 
 padding-bottom:0\9; //IE 8 and below
 padding-left:12px;
 padding-right:12px;
 padding-top:10px;  
 padding-top:0\9; //IE 8 and below
```

}

If these are the only IE-specific styles you need, this is probably easier than using a conditional style sheet.